# Use custom header, instead of query params to rewrite URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

*I've been brainstorming about resolving one issue, that I really want to achieve for personal project purposes. Now, I believe that such a thing, that I will talk about, is possible, but I couldn't dig anything on Google. So either nobody ever needed to do something like this or nobody ever just thought to even test it, for fun at least.
To go through all the stuff that are on my mind right now, I will begin by simply setting our fake domain and fake project structure.*

**Domain:**

`example.org`

**Structure:**

```
root/
├── dir-one/
│   ├── scripts/
│   ├── styles/
│   └── index.php
├── dir-two/
│   ├── scripts/
│   ├── styles/
│   └── index.php
└── index.php
```

**We're running `apache` server and using `php` as server-side language.**

---

That being said, I can now explain what do we have here.
Let's say, that our root `index.php` file simply `requires` one or another directory, depending on an variable which is determined by some way...

So, contents of `root/index.php` would look something like this:

```
<?php

$case = $determine ? 'dir-one' : 'dir-two';

require_once "$case/index.php";

?>
```

However, the contents of `dir-one/index.php` and `dir-two/index.php` have relative paths for resources.

```
<link href="/styles/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

So those will obviously load when we visit:

`example.org/one-dir`

But they won't be working in our case where we just visit:

`example.org`

Our `php` requires that directory, but all our relative paths are now broken. In order to resolve this, I thought about `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`.

These things crossed my mind:

1. Can we somehow tell apache, that our resources are available within `dir_one` or `dir_two` depending on which one is `required`?
2. We could've use `queries` and instead of requiring one dir or another, we could tell our server through `.htaccess` file what to show to the user. For example: `example.org/?page=one` (we'd rewrite that to show actually `dir_one/index.php` if that's even possible? Would our resources work now? I think so...
3. But what if I don't want to have any visible query parameters, because it's only one dir or another, depending on the case... So this time, I thought about setting custom `headers` which we could set through `php` and our `apache` would be able to access them, right? I truly hope so... I mean, I read somewhere that we can access them, but can we read actual value from it or just check if the header is present?

So, we are changing our `root/index.php` file contents to:

```
<?php

$case = $determine ? 'dir-one' : 'dir-two';

header("C-Load: $case");

?>
```

Now, what I am hoping to achieve is the same as with `query` parameters, but in this case, reading the value from the custom `header` if the header is present, which will always be the case. The value will be either `dir-one` or `dir-two` depending on the determination result.

*I have no real knowledge of `.htaccess` and I can only do basic stuff, but I am going to dig now with the shovel called Google and I truly hope that I can figure something out on my own. Heck, I did not even test if our `relative` paths would work if we use `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` to show one dir or the other. But if that is possible, I'm sure as hell we can do it with `header` too...
Any kind of help, pointers, articles or even solutions would've been appreciated.*

---

**Update #1:**

After further digging, I haven't found solution yet, but I think I am near... However, for some reason, it seems like I cannot compare to the value of `%{HTTP:header}`?

**PHP**

```
<?php

header("X-Load-Directory: one");

?>
```

**APACHE (.htaccess)**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Load-Directory} ^one$
RewriteRule ^$ /dir-one/index.php [L]
```

As far as I am concerned, this should be working just fine, but it does not. It never passes the `Cond`.

**Update #2:**

Another update... I just realised that maybe I cannot do such a thing from within my own server. So I have used `Postman` to send an `GET` request to my own localhost with custom header as mentioned above `X-Load-Directory` and in this case it does work. It actually picks up on that header, which means I cannot set that header from php and then access it from `htaccess`. Yeh, logically the order makes no sense now when I think about it.

Comment: 1) No - your require is PHP, the rest is HTTP. No connection. 3) Nope, not possible either, a) wrong order, and b) no connection between the initial request that loaded the page, and the ones that load the external resources.

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging a while now and I found one very simple solution with `html` tag, which would work...

In our `dir-one/index.php` and `dir-two/index.php` we'd need to add this tag and specify `href` to the corresponding directory...

```
<base href="/dir-one/">
```

And tweak our paths a little bit by removing first forward slash `/`...

```
<link href="styles/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

> P.S. I did not know that `/styles/app.css` is an absolute path, because it starts with forward slash.

Now, when we `require` it in `php` those relative paths would work just fine.

---

But, I am still aiming to figure out the other two ways from my question.

1. Resolve it using `.htaccess` and `query` strings to determine which directory to load as root.
2. Resolve it using `.htaccess` and custom `headers` to determine which directory to load as root.

Cause maybe in these two cases, I can avoid touching relative path resources from either directory and it'd magically work?